# Sort a List of a Tuple.. of a list. Case insensitive

Tags: python

So what I have currently is a string that looks like this,

```
hello here, hello there, hello Everywhere
```

I'm making a iteration of kwic if anyone knows what that is. The format that is required is a list of tuples.. of list while sorting case insensitive. So in the end I have a unsorted list that looks like

```
(['here,', 'hello', 'there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello'], 0)
(['hello', 'there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,'], 0)
(['there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,', 'hello'], 0)
(['hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,', 'hello', 'there,'], 0)
(['Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,', 'hello', 'there,', 'hello'], 0)
(['hello', 'here,', 'hello', 'there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere'], 0)`
```

Currently I am using a python sort like

```
Final_Array.sort(key = lambda a: a[0][0].lower())
```

But that gives me a sorted list that looks like

```
(['Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,', 'hello', 'there,', 'hello'], 0)
(['hello', 'there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,'], 0)
(['hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,', 'hello', 'there,'], 0)
(['hello', 'here,', 'hello', 'there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere'], 0)
(['here,', 'hello', 'there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello'], 0)
(['there,', 'hello', 'Everywhere', 'hello', 'here,', 'hello'], 0)`
```

Obviously the `hello Everywhere` should be before the `hello there`, along with `hello here`.
It's sorting based on sending the first word  of the accessed list to lower, but I need it to sort and compare all entries of the accessed list so that there if there is a tie it just keeps comparing the next value in the array and the next, all while ignoring case.

Comment: You are accessing the first word only, you need to lower every word,  `lambda a: list(map(str.lower, a[0]))`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, I have been stuck on that forever.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Final_Array.sort(key=lambda x: list(map(str.lower, x[0])))
```

Comment: `map` only needs wrapping in a sequence constructor (e.g. `list`) on Py3 (on Py2, it returns sequences). And as long as you need the wrapping on Py3, may as well use `tuple` instead of `list`, `tuple` is slightly better optimized for constant/fixed length usage.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your sort is only taking into account the first word in the list.  In order to make it sort lexicographically based on *all* the words in the list, your sort key should return a *list* of lower-cased words (one lower-cased word for each word in the input list)

```
def sort_key(t):
    word_list, integer = t
    return [word.lower() for word in word_list]

Final_Array.sort(key=sort_key)
```

<sup>Due to the complexity of the sort, I'd prefer to avoid the lambda in this case, but not everyone necessarily agrees with that opinion :-)</sup>

Comment: That would be a perfectly cromulent lambda. `lambda t: [w.lower() for w in t[0]]`

Comment: @kindall -- You're welcome to use that as a lambda, but the line starts to get illegible pretty quickly when you throw the rest of it in there (IMHO):  `Final_Array.sort(key=lambda t: [w.lower() for w in t[0]])`.  I'm left thinking to myself -- What's `t[0]`?  What's `w`?.  Depending on the indentation level, you may go over your 80 character limit and then you need to figure out where to break your statement ... Call me verbose, but I'd prefer the extra function :-)

Comment: So this is also trying to be a rather fast sort, aside from the complexity of the sort, wouldn't tossing a function as the key not a lambda cause some overhead? I guess what I'm trying to say is would a lambda be faster or a function? I thought lambda's were just arbitrary functions anyways?

Comment: @Dringo -- using a `lambda` won't be faster at least not in any way that is appreciable and perhaps not even in ways that aren't appreciable.  To define a `lambda`, AFAIK, python does everything that it does when it defines a regular function.  Inspecting the bytecode with `dis` seems to also validate this assertion.